# How can I remove banding noise from this image?

Tags: banding

[image: Thick Horizontal Noises]

I'm an complete newbie in photography and I'm trying to use the Sigma 70-300mm F4-5.6 APO lens and a Guppy camera(you can think of it as a processor that captures light rather than an actual camera) to capture the image of an electrospinning process. I use a computer monitor to see the images that the camera captures.

The problem is that on the screen, there are these thick horizontal bands, making the images undesirable. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Lol a photo of a photo on a screen. Can you upload the photo vs taking a picture of your monitor?

Comment: I actually just need to get rid of the black horizontal bars on the screen...when i turn the shutterspeed up, the bars will turn transparent to faint pink but still there... Should i just change to a better monitor? Thanks! @ths

Comment: turn the shutterspeed down, not up.

Comment: Tell us the shutter speed and the nature of the lighting of the banded image.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the refresh of yur monitor, probably 60Hz. You can prevent that by shooting at a longer shutter speed, which means reducing the ISO value and/or your aperture (=bigger aperture number). Just try a few different settings.

A tripod will probably be helpful, to prevent camera shake at those slow speeds.

Edit: i'm just seeing that you posted *a photo of a screen displaying a photo*. And i don't really know what a guppy camera or an electrospinning process are. Still, it's probably the same principle.

Comment: Google shows Guppy cameras as compact firewire cameras for (e.g.) robot and induatrial uses. It's a cmos sensor, so maybe the OP is confused, or has a more specific meaning of *camera* (though we use the term *webcam* and video camera, so I would call that a camera)